# Oracle SQL join three tables and group by column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have three tables and I want a query te select teacher names and the number of classes each teacher has reserved.

teacher:

```
| idt | name |
```

class:

```
| idc | name |
```

reserve:

```
| idc | idt |
```

My query:

```
select
  t.name, count(distinct(r.idc))
  from
  teacher t
  join 
  reserve r
  on
  r.idt = t.idt
  join
  class c
  on
  c.idc = r.idc
  group by r.idc
```

When I run this I get the followin error: `not a group by expression.`

Comment: You should be grouping on the selecting columns that are additional to the aggregate function (COUNT in this case). Try grouping by t.name.

Comment: `group by t.name`.  The `group by` fields should match the fields in the `select`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `group by` clause needs to contain all non-aggregated columns from the `select` statement; in your case it should be `t.name`. Also, `distinct` is not a function but a keyword and should not have parentheses.

```
select
  t.name, 
  count(distinct r.idc) as number_of_classes
from
  teacher t
join 
  reserve r on r.idt = t.idt
join
  class c on c.idc = r.idc
group by 
  t.name
```